# how to animate custom property in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have drawn one line.I have added AngleProperty in my view. Using that angle property i need to animate that line to that angle.

Here is my View in which line is drawn

```
public class DrawView : View
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        private double mvalue = 90;
         public double Angle
        {
            get { return mvalue; }
            set { 
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(this, "Angle", (float)this.Angle, (float)value);
                anim.SetDuration(500);
                anim.Start();
                mvalue = value;

            }
        }
        public DrawView(Context context):base(context)
        {
            paint.Color = Color.Green;
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
            Value = Angle* Math.Pi / 180;
        var startX = 300;
        var startY = 300;
        var endX = 500 + 40 * Math.Sin(Value);
        var endY = 500 + 40 * Math.Cos(Value);

        canvas.DrawLine(startX, startY, (float)endX, (float)endY, paint);        
        }
    }
```

In main Activity, i have added button in which angle is given,

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        DrawView drawview;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
 drawview = new DrawView(this);
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.SetHeight(50);
            b.SetWidth(50);
            b.Click += B_Click;
            LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
            lay.AddView(b);
            lay.AddView(drawview);
}
 private void B_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            drawview.Angle= 180;
        }
}
```

Anyone please suggest how to animate that line to certain angle

Answer (score 0):

Logic is correct, but there are several problems. Since you have defined a Angle property, you should use the `Angle` property to control the Animation instead of using `Value` property, then it can work fine like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUUNF.gif). For more information, you could read the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html).

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        Angle = Angle * Math.PI / 180;
        var startX = 300;
        var startY = 300;
        var endX = 500 + 40 * Math.Sin(Angle);
        var endY = 500 + 40 * Math.Cos(Angle);

        canvas.DrawLine(startX, startY, (float)endX, (float)endY, paint);
    }
```

When click a button, start the `Animation`:

```
private void B_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //certain angle decided by EditText's text
        Int32 number = int.Parse(et.Text.ToString());
        drawview.Angle = number;
    }
```